# Analog of __non_webpack_require__ for Vue Cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, require, vue-cli

I need to load some metadata at startup and when working with webpack I used `__non_webpack_require__`, but the Vue Cli does not know such a method. Is there an analog that does not package the specified module and converts it to `require(path)`?